AWS Locking API Versions in V3
In AWS API V2 we had the property apiVersion.
see reference in the documentation
In AWS API v3 I do not see any reference in the documentation for this property.
Is this property deprecated ?

Is this a question about the Javascript SDK?

Yes. Javascript SDK
